# gradle kts compileGeneratedJava FAILED

Tags: java, gradle

We use gradle 7.6.2 and jdk 17
There is following build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {

    implementation(group = "jakarta.xml.ws", name = "jakarta.xml.ws-api", version = jaxwsToolsVersion)
    implementation(group = "jakarta.xml.bind", name = "jakarta.xml.bind-api", version = jaxwsToolsVersion)
    compileOnly(group = "jakarta.jws", name = "jakarta.jws-api", version = "3.0.0")

    ...
}


wsdl2java {
    groups {
        register("wsdl1") {
            wsdlDir.set(layout.projectDirectory.dir("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdls"))
            includes.set(listOf("MessageService.wsdl"))
            packageName.set("com.service.mom")
            generatedSourceDir.set(layout.projectDirectory.dir("$buildDir/generated/wsdl1/src/main/java"))
        }
        register("wsld2") {
            wsdlDir.set(layout.projectDirectory.dir("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdls"))
            includes.set(listOf("SREngine.wsdl"))
            packageName.set("com.service.rpt.engine")
            generatedSourceDir.set(layout.projectDirectory.dir("$buildDir/generated/wsdl2/src/main/java"));
        }
      
    }
}

val generated: SourceSet by sourceSets.creating {
    java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/wsdl1/src/main/java")
    java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/wsdl2/src/main/java")
}

sourceSets.main.configure {
    java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/wsdl1/src/main/java")
    java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/wsdl2/src/main/java")

    compileClasspath += generated.output
    runtimeClasspath += generated.output
}

tasks.compileJava {
    dependsOn("wsdl2java")
}
```

Build fails with following error:

> Task :server:compileGeneratedJava FAILED
> C:\work\sandbox\web\server\build\generated\wsdl1\src\main\java\com\service\mom\Acknowledge.java:4: error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
> import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

I suppose that dependencies not available in generate classes compilation task
How to configure generate sources classpath?